# Is this a function shadowing error?

Tags: r, package, data.table, shadowing

Nothing applicable came up in search, but I ran into this error when installing a package in R:

```
> install.packages("entropy")
Loading required package: stats

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "data.table"
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘entropy’ had non-zero exit status
```

Now, I had `data.table` loaded in this running session. When I ran another R session as root and installed this package with no new packages loaded, it finished with no errors, and I can load this package into the initial session with no problem.

Where is this error coming from, and is it going to give me possible bad output if I have `data.table` loaded at the same time?

edit: output of `conflicts()`:

```
> conflicts()
 [1] "rename"          "round_any"       "freqs"           "show"            "plot"           
 [6] "rootogram"       "cloud"           "layer"           "colsplit"        "french_fries"   
[11] "melt"            "recast"          "smiths"          "tips"            "coef"           
[16] "filter"          "fitted"          "poly"            "predict"         "plot"           
[21] "prompt"          "npk"             "initialize"      "show"            "as.Date"        
[26] "as.Date.numeric" "body<-"          "formals<-"       "kronecker"
```

The list of installed packages is available at [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tyLayjUf) since it's quite long.

Comment: Please list the exact commands you ran to reproduce this error. It is unclear to me what you are doing exactly. It seems like you just didn't call `library(data.table)` in this session. Also `conflicts()` can show all the functions that are shadowed by other libraries and such.

Comment: Repeating `install.packages("entropy")` after `library(data.table)` didn't change the error. I added the output of `conflicts()` also, thanks for that tip.

Comment: Is this a clean R session? Seems odd you have have all those conflicts. Maybe you can update your question to also include the specific version numbers of the packages you have. You can see that with `installed.pacakges`. It doesn't appear that entropy has a dependency on data.table or even has a function named data.table itself. It seems odd.

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick: seems odd. I tried briefly anyway and couldn't reproduce. Need more detail please starting with a fresh session perhaps with `--vanilla` and building up from there.

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I can reproduce it with those steps later.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Did you make any attempt to solve this matter? If you found a solution, could you add it as an answer? If not, can you create a more reproducible error?

Comment: Sorry I haven't gotten to this yet, this is a busy week for me. I ran into the same error again after re-opening a project file in RStudio, but I haven't traced it yet. (There's no deadline on SO questions...right?)